# sed replace only first occurrence, then only second occurrence, then only third

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a string like this:

```
chair melon cow pushing danced chair chair pushing cow danced
```

I want to have sed replace the first occurrence of `chair` the first time around:

```
REPLACED melon cow pushing danced chair chair pushing cow danced
```

then the second:

```
chair melon cow pushing danced REPLACED chair pushing cow danced
```

and then the third:

```
chair melon cow pushing danced chair REPLACED pushing cow danced
```

I can create the loop and +1 increase myself, I just need to know if sed (BSD or GNU doesn't matter) allows for something like this by specifying an integer.

Almost like: `sed $number',/chair/{s/chair/REPLACED/}'`, even though that would not work the way I want. I just put that there to show that I'm looking to input an integer from variable.

I don't mind using `awk` but really, really prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. If I got your question correctly, following will substitute 1st occurrence of `chair` only. Tested and written with GNU `sed`.

```
echo "chair melon cow pushing danced chair chair pushing cow danced" | 
sed 's/chair/REPLACE/1'
```

***NOTE:*** One important point to be noted here, lets say you have run this command  1st time and replaced very first occurrence of chair then in next try you want to substitute 2nd occurrence which has become now 1st occurrence of chair since 1st one was already replaced with new text, so be careful while using it. Thought to mention it here.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you for the quick answer! This even worked on BSD `sed` (using El Capitan)

Comment: Finally, a simple answer to a simple problem. Thanks!